# better way to write nested foreach loop, multiple array comparison php

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 multidimensional arrays. I run the first one through a `foreach` loop to gain data from it. then run the second `foreach` loop inside the first creating a nested `foreach` loop.then inside the second `foreach` loop I run an if statement to compare a value from the first array to the second array and display some output which works, however I am a little concerned about long run-time. so my question is, is there a cleaner, neater way to write it with a shorter run type:

```
@foreach($arrayOne as $firstArray)
    @foreach($arrayTwo as $secondArray)
        @if($firstArray['id'] == $secondArray['linkedId'])
            /*output some data*/
        @endif
    @endforeach      
@endforeach
```

Comment: It is unclear whether, and what, you want to use of the arrays inside the foreach loops. This is important to know. You also don't give us any idea about the content of the array, and why you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity of two-nested-foreach solution is `O(n * k)`, where `n = len(array1)` and `k = len(array2)`. However you can achieve a smaller complexity `O(n + k)` via using hash tables (assoc arrays in PHP world).

```
$twoByLinkedId = [];
foreach ($arrayTwo as $x) {  // K iterations
    if (empty($twoByLinkedId[$x['linkedId']])) {
        $twoByLinkedId[$x['linkedId']] = [];
    }
    array_push($twoByLinkedId[$x['linkedId']], $x);
}

foreach ($arrayOne as $el) {  // N iterations
    $entries = empty($twoByLinkedId[$el['id']]) 
        ? [] 
        : $twoByLinkedId[$el['id']];
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {  // only few iterations
        /* output $entry */
    }
}
```

So you can see that the complexity of the solution is `O(k + n*t)`, where `t` is a a small number.

Of course, the trick makes sense only if the lengths of both arrays are really big, otherwise simple nested foreach is a good solution too.

Comment: thanks so much, Ive used this O(n * k) method many many times before, and everytime i use it I feel like im writing "dirty" code but i have never known the science behind it.